# Which comes first, POST or BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

I'm sort of confused as to which comes first during boot up, the POST test or the BIOS.  Some places say the POST test is a function of the BIOS, and that the BIOS initially loads it.  Others say the POST test is triggered as soon as the machine receives power, and the POST test is responsible for loading the BIOS.

Which to believe?

Answer (score 1):

POST is handled by the BIOS and runs as the BIOS is "turning on" devices on and connected to the motherboard.

[Power-On Slef-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test)